# Using Rows.InsertAt enters blank row

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

I have a listBox with a DataTable datasource.  I am trying to create a button that will move a DataRow up the DataTable.

This is the code that i am trying.  But when it runs, it removes the correct Datarow, but inserts a blank row in the correct place.

```
DataRow row;            
row = SelectedPlayersHome.Rows[selectedIndex];
int temp = SelectedPlayersHome.Rows.IndexOf(row);
SelectedPlayersHome.Rows.RemoveAt(temp);
SelectedPlayersHome.Rows.InsertAt(row, temp - 1);
```

Even though i am creating a copy of the row, it appear that when i remove the row from the table, it deletes the data from the newly created row.

Ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing so:

```
row = SelectedPlayersHome.Rows[selectedIndex];
```

In fact you are not creating a copy of the row, but you assign a reference of the row to `row` variable.

You should do sth like this:

```
DataRow row = SelectedPlayersHome.NewRow();             
DataRow selectedRow= SelectedPlayersHome.Rows[selectedIndex];
row.ItemArray= selectedRow.ItemArray; // <-- copy data
SelectedPlayersHome.Rows.Remove(selectedRow);
SelectedPlayersHome.Rows.InsertAt(row, selectedIndex +1/-1); // depending if you want to go up or down
```

Comment: Reason is correct, but that doesn't answers question how to fix problem

Comment: I kind of had a feeling that what the problem was, but not 100% sure.  So how would i combat this?

Comment: I think you should use `SelectedPlayersHome.NewRow()` instead of `new DataRow()`

Comment: Nice work chaps.  That has worked a treat.  I had tried researching this problem, but unfortunately google only shows how to insert a blank row.  Thanks.